# using less instead of css totally and attach .less to head tag

Tags: css, less

im new to less framework 
i wanna know can i use less instead of css totally ?

and i attached less.js and my style.less to head tag like

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>(correctly url and names)
```

and in my style.less i have been write

```
@color: #5B83AD;

body { backgorund : @color  }
```

but i had'nt been see any changes . now whats the problem ? im using Wamp

thanks

Comment: Try adding a `;` after `@color`.

Comment: Did your replace **(correctly url and names)**  by a correct ressource url ? Are your files 'style.less' and 'less.js'  at the root of your project's page ?

Comment: yeah , directory/index.html , style.less and less.js

Comment: @CatoCato Did you fix your issue ?? Co you still need help with this ?

Answer (score 2):

**backgorund : @color**

You should try  **background** : @color

If you'd [use a compiler](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js) you'd have receive a notification about the typo error

Comment: Well spotted! Didn't see that after skimming it a few times.

Comment: Does this means it fixed your situation and this is an accepted answer ?

Comment: @Catocato Did you fix your issue ?? Co you still need help with this ?